# How do I make an if statement not execute and go to the else if statement if one or more variables are less than 0?

Tags: java, if-statement

Ok so I am new to java and for some reason the else if is only executed when all 3 of the variables are below 0. How can I fix it so if one of them is less than 0 it does the error message?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class ChristianBondurant_3_05 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      //Declaring all needed variables at the top.
      double a, b, c; //declares the sides of the triangle"      
      double perimeter;
      double s;
      double area;
      StringTokenizer st;
      String inputStr = new String();
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");

      inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the sides of the triangle seperated by spaces: ");

      st = new StringTokenizer(inputStr);
      a = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());//Enter your A variable
      b = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());//Enter your B variable
      c = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());;//Enter your C variable 

      //Making our variables equivlent to these equations.
      if (a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0){
      perimeter = a + b + c;
      s = perimeter / 2;
      area = Math.sqrt(s * ( s - a ) * ( s - b ) * ( s - c ));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Sides of the Triangle are: " + 
             + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + "\n" +
             "The Perimeter is :" + perimeter + "\n" +
             "The area formatted to one decimal place: " + df.format(area) +"\n" +
             "The area unformatted: " + area + "\n");
      }

      else if(a < 0 || b < 0 || c <0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Please enter an integer.");
      }
   }
}
```

Sorry if this has been asked I tried searching for my question but I found nothing on it.

Comment: neither of those if blocks will run if all of the vars are EQUAL to 0, ... just saying... one of them should probably have an equals sign with the comparison operator

Comment: also, do you really need an else if... why not just an else... PSUEDO, if any of these 3 vars is > 0, do something, ELSE do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping logic here.  If even one of the 3 variables is greater than 0 then the elseif will never be called here.  Else is only called if the first if conditions are not met.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you could do

```
if(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
//codehere
else
//codehere
```

Or maybe you want to do both in which case you should have 2 different if statements.

```
if(a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0)
{
//code here
}
if(a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0)
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: The top one worked perfectly, thanks! I will mark as correct once it will allow me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
//Making our variables equivlent to these equations.
if (a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0) {
```

This means: "If any of `a`, `b` and `c` are positive"

You seem to want to say:

```
// If a, b and c are all positive
if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0) {
```

Or possibly what you want is:

```
// If a, b and c are all non-negative
if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0) {
```

and then your else clause can just have:

```
// otherwise, a, b or c must be negative
else {
    ...
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition should logically be

```
a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

as the intial if condition is wrong as you are using the || operator and the condition is fullfiled even if the one is true use && operator.then the if will only work when all the no. are greater then 0.

```
if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0) {
```